# getting a matrix for translation - glm does it differently

Tags: linear-algebra

The OpenGL maths library(GLM) uses the following algorithm to compute the translation matrix:

```
//taken from source code
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, Q> translate(mat<4, 4, T, Q> const& m, vec<3, T, Q> const& v)
{
    mat<4, 4, T, Q> Result(m);
    Result[3] = m[0] * v[0] + m[1] * v[1] + m[2] * v[2] + m[3];
    return Result;
}
```

(Here the vector **v** is a 3 dimensional vector and the matrix m is a 4X4 matrix, since we're using homogeneous coordinates the vector **v** is also 4 dimensional).

let **m** have the entries:

$$ m =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c & d  \\
e & f & g & h\\
i & j & k & l\\
m & n & o & p\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

now, suppose the matrix **m** gives some linear transformation, and is also a transformation matrix, and we'd like to add a translation of X, Y, and Z in the X, Y and Z dimensions respectively, if I'm not mistaken, the way we'd do that is by forming a composite matrix:

$$
 tm =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & X  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & Y\\
0 & 0 & 1 & Z\\
0 & 0 & o & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}.
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c & d  \\
e & f & g & h\\
i & j & k & l\\
m & n & o & p\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

which gives something like:
$$ tm=
\begin{pmatrix}
a+X & b+X & c+X & d+X  \\
e+Y & f+Y & g+Y & h+Y\\
i+Z & j+Z & k+Z & l+Z\\
m & n & o & p\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Now, I'm not getting what this GLM function of translate does, because it does something like: 
$$ X.
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
e \\
i \\
m \\
\end{pmatrix}
+Y.
\begin{pmatrix}
b \\
f \\
j \\
n \\
\end{pmatrix} 
+Z.
\begin{pmatrix}
c \\
g \\
k \\
o \\
\end{pmatrix} 
+
\begin{pmatrix}
d \\
h \\
l \\
p \\
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
H1 \\
H2 \\
H3 \\
H4 \\
\end{pmatrix} (let)
$$

And the matrix with added transformation of translation, i.e. **m**  becomes:
$$   
   \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c & H1  \\
e & f & g & H2\\
i & j & k & H3\\
m & n & o & H4\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Now, these two matrices are not equal and hence they would result in different transformations, so I'm confused to which matrix does the actual translation and which is the correct one or if there is any other idea hidden behind the algorithm?

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it assumes that `m` represents an affine transformation, with last row equal to $(0,0,0,1)$. That seems reasonable for building the model matrix, since that generally only involves affine transformations.

Comment: could you give me more lead on this please? `m` does represent a 3 dimensional coordinate system, but I thought that was for maintaining a homogeneous coordinate system